# When do you have to use a view instead of joining? - SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms

My professor stated that certain queries need to use a view, instead of a join because a join will calculate values multiple times - producing an incorrect result.  Why does this happen?  And how does a view protect from that?

Comment: I don't think you ever "have" to use a view instead of just using derived queries - subject to RDBMS limitations. Using a view (or not) *shouldn't* affect the "number of calculations" - excluding things like Materialized/Indexed Views of course.

Comment: Are they his exact words?

Comment: "You may also be asked to explain why some of the queries in assignment 8 have to be completed in two steps (views). For example you may be asked to explain why we can't join saleitem and orderitem by showing actual rows in the relevant tables and the result of such a join"

Comment: I think they are referring to joining one table with the aggregated data of another table. You cannot really do this in one "step" so this is achieved using a subquery (or a view with a similar query to the subquery).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a view in place of a join then your view probably contains a join. A view is simply a stored query. It presents to you a virtual single table but may be made up of joins across many tables, or it may contain aggregated data.

Based on that, I'm assuming there is more to your professors logic because your statement doesn't make sense.